# Многофазная сортировка

Tags: c++, c, сортировка

Помогите разобраться с алгоритмом внешней многофазной сортировки. Опишите алгоритм, либо же, вдруг у кого-то есть код реализации на с/с++, буду весьма благодарен.

Comment: В Кнуте ж вроде алгоритм есть?

Comment: Я не спец по вычметодам, но, к примеру, эта публикация должна, ИМХО, пролить свет: http://cpct.sibsutis.ru/~artpol/downloads/prog/2012_2013/s2/prog_s2_lect5p4_v6.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Цитаты с книги:

На первом шаге мы прочитаем S записей и отсортируем их с помощью подходящей внутренней сортировки. Этот набор уже отсортированных записей перепишем в файл А. Затем прочитаем еще S записей, отсортируем их и перепишем в файл В. Этот процесс продолжается, причем отсортированные блоки записей пишутся попеременно то в файл А, то в файл В. Вот алгоритм, реализующий первый этап:

```
CreateRuns(S)
S размер создаваемых отрезков
CurrentFile=A
while конец входного файла не достигнут do
    read S записей из входного файла
    sort S записей
    if CurrentFile=A then
        CurrentFile=B
    else
        CurrrentFile=A
    end if
end while
```

После того, как входной файл полностью разбит на отсортированные отрезки, мы готовы перейти ко второму шагу - - слиянию этих отрезков. Каждый из файлов А и В содержит некоторую последова-
тельность отсортированных отрезков, однако, как и в случае сортировки слиянием, мы ничего не можем сказать о порядке записей в двух различных отрезках.
Процесс слияния будет аналогичен функции MergeLists из § 3.6, однако теперь вместо того, чтобы переписывать записи в новый массив, мы будем записывать их в новый файл. Поэтому мы начинаем с чтения половинок первых отрезков из файлов А и В. Читаем мы лишь по половине отрезков, поскольку мы уже выяснили, что в памяти может находиться одновременно лишь S записей, а нам нужны записи из обоих файлов. Будем теперь сливать эти половинки отрезков в один отрезок файла С. После того, как одна из половинок закончится, мы прочтем вторую половинку из того же файла. Когда обработка одного из отрезков будет завершена, конец второго отрезка будет переписан
в файл С. После того, как слияние первых двух отрезков из файлов А и В будет завершено, следующие два отрезка сливаются в файл D. Этот процесс слияния отрезков продолжается с попеременной записью слитых отрезков в файлы С и D. По завершении мы получаем два файла,
разбитых на отсортированные отрезки длины 2S. Затем процесс повторяется, причем отрезки читаются из файлов С и D, а слитые отрезки длины 4S записываются в файлы А и В. Ясно, что в конце концов отрезки сольются в один отсортированный список в одном из файлов.
Вот алгоритм осуществления второго этапа:

```
PolyPhaseMerge(S)
S размер исходных отрезков
Size=S
Input1=A
Input2=B
Current Output=C
while not done do
    while отрезки не кончились do
        слить отрезок длины Size из файла Input1
            с отрезком длины Size из файла Input2
            записав результат в CurrentOutput
        if (CurrentOutput=A) then
            CurrentOutput=B
        elsif (CurrentOutput=B) then
            CurrrentOutput=A
        elsif (CurrentOutput=C) then
        Currrent Output=D
        elsif (CurrentOutput=D) then
            CurrrentOutput=C
        end if
    end while
    Size=Size*2
    if (Input1=A) then
        Input1=C
        Input2=D
        Current Output=A
    else
        Input1=A
        Input2=B
        CurrentOutput=C
    end if
end while
```

Ссылка: http://www.sql.ru/forum/722812/mnogofaznaya-sortirovka